# PHP Comparing two CSV files and highlight the difference

Tags: php, csv

I want to compare two CSV files and highlight the difference where it occurs. At the moment I have a small script that reads both CSV files and prints out the content on to the browser. these files are structured the same in term of column number but the values in some rows are different and I would like to highlight this difference but not to sure where to start from:

PHP Code:

```
<?php
$file = fopen("try.csv","r");
$file2 = fopen("try2.csv", "r");

if(! feof($file)){

    while($data = fgetcsv($file))
    {
        foreach($data as $element){
            echo $element.'   ';
        }

        echo '<br />';


    }
}

echo '<br />';
echo ">>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>New File<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<";
echo '<br />';

if(! feof($file2)){

    while($data = fgetcsv($file2))
    {
        foreach($data as $element2){
            echo $element2.'   ';
        }

        echo '<br />';


    }
}


fclose($file);
?>
```

Knowing that the variables `$element` & `$element2` hold the CSV content how can I find the differences....?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`fgetcsv` returns an array for the current row, so if memory isn't an issue, you could pull in the rows of the first csv and store each row in an array like `$csv_1` and then the second as `$csv_2` and then use [`array_udiff`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-udiff.php) to find the non-overlapping rows.

```
function row_compare($a, $b)
{
    if ($a === $b) {
        return 0;
    }

    return (implode("",$a) < implode("",$b) ) ? -1 : 1;
}

$file1 = new SplFileObject("try.csv");
$file1->setFlags(SplFileObject::READ_CSV);

$file2 = new SplFileObject("try2.csv");
$file2->setFlags(SplFileObject::READ_CSV);

foreach ($file1 as $row) {
    $csv_1[] = $row;
}

foreach ($file2 as $row) {
    $csv_2[] = $row;
}

$unique_to_csv1 = array_udiff($csv_1, $csv_2, 'row_compare');
$unique_to_csv2 = array_udiff($csv_2, $csv_1, 'row_compare');

$all_unique_rows = array_merge($unique_to_csv1,$unique_to_csv2);

foreach($all_unique_rows as $unique_row) {
    foreach($unique_row as $element) {
        echo $element . "   ";
    }
    echo '<br />';
}
```

Comment: Hi when I try your answer i get multiple of this error: `Notice: Array to string conversion in /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/Comp/test.php on line 15`

Comment: are you trying to echo out `$all_unique_rows` ? that's not allowed, since echo outputs values that can be converted to strings (which non-scalar variables can't). Try `print_r($all_unique_rows)` or if you are outputting for user, you'll need a foreach loop for the outer array of rows and an inner foreach loop for getting the value of each field for the row. Updated answer to make this more clear.

Comment: thank you so much..as I understand this shows all the unique rows where there was no changes..?

Comment: I am assuming two independent CSVs that potentially have overlapping data. This will output the rows unique to file1 in the array `$unique_to_csv1` (so they appear in file1, not in file2) and will output the rows unique to file2 in the array `$unique_to_csv2`. If you need to indicate which file the unique row was found, I would skip the `array_merge` step and handle the first array with some header like "These rows were File 1 but not File 2" and then the reverse for the second array.

Comment: Also, I was originally mistaken in thinking that `array_diff` would handle an array of arrays and just treat the sub-arrays as variables (so that it did a simple compare of the rows as arrays without a deeper dive into the array contents), but it turns out that just returns an empty array. So I updated answer to use `array_udiff` which uses a callback, and the comparison in the callback uses `implode` to convert the row arrays into a long string. In any case, it does not highlight what field changed between CSVs, only that the row as a whole is unique.

Answer (score 0):

this code take me time, but now, it can be simplest?

```
$filename="nomes.csv"; //lista completa 
$base="track.opened.csv"; //mark if it is on here 
$NOWcodes = array();

$file = fopen($base, 'r'); //registred opened 
while (($line = fgetcsv($file)) !== FALSE) { array_push($NOWcodes, $line[0]);  }
fclose($file);

$file = fopen($filename, 'r'); //all nomes 
while (($line = fgetcsv($file)) !== FALSE) {

if(!in_array($line[0],$NOWcodes)){$inscrito='yellow;';}
else{$inscrito='#9999ff;';} 

echo '<span style="background-color: '.$inscrito.'" title="'.$line[0].'">'.$line[2].'</span><br>'; }
fclose($file);
```